# Visual Studio 2013 project vanished upon clicking no to "save all"

Tags: visual-studio-2013, solution, disaster-recovery

I am using VS 2013 Shell Integrated with TwinCat3. Never seen this one before... Simply wanted to save some code and visualization changes and "save all" was defaulting to an F: drive that did not exist. I clicked cancel and retried a few times, no result. Clicked "X" to exit VS and I got the same prompt, so I clicked "No" and I watched everything in my solution disappear, as if I had just made a new one. Upon restarting VS and looking in the "recent projects and solutions" I cannot see the said solution in there anymore. When I check the directory with file explorer everything in it is gone. I have a backup but it costs me about 16 hours of work, and it wont compile.

Answer (score 0):

Check temp folder for visual studio